# Using actionPerformed() to call different methods per radio button selection

Tags: java, swing, form, event-handling

My Java is very rusty and I have been unlucky finding a better way to accomplish this task.  I have two different methods which get called based on which radio button is selected.  Is there a cleaner way to store/determine which radio button is currently selected in order to call the appropriate method? Here is the segment I am trying to streamline. (Full source code below)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == iterativeRadio){
        calcMethod = "iterative";
    }else if(e.getSource() == recursiveRadio){
        calcMethod = "recursive";
    }else if(calcMethod == null){
        resultBox.setText("Select a calculation method");
    }else{
        try{
            int n = Integer.parseInt(inputBox.getText());
            if (e.getSource() == calcButton){
                if(calcMethod == "iterative"){
                    resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.computeIterative(n)));
                    efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.getEfficiency()));
                }else if(calcMethod == "recursive"){
                    resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.computeRecursive(n)));
                    efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.getEfficiency()));
                }
            }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e2){
            resultBox.setText("Invalid entry");
        }catch (ArithmeticException e3){
            resultBox.setText(e3.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e4){
            resultBox.setText("Something bad happened");
        }
    }
}
```

Sequence.java:

```
/**
 * @author Matthew Miller
 * Sequence utility class
 */

public final class Sequence {
    private static int efficiency;

    public static int getEfficiency(){
        return efficiency;
    }

    public static int computeIterative (int n){
        efficiency = 0;
        return iterativeWorker(0,1,n);
    }

    private static int iterativeWorker(int onePrev, int curr, int n){
        if (n == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            int twoPrev;
            for(int i = curr; i < n; i++){
                efficiency++;
                twoPrev = onePrev;
                onePrev = curr;
                curr = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(2, onePrev), twoPrev);
            }
            return curr;
        }
    }

    public static int computeRecursive (int n){
        efficiency = 0;
        return recursiveWorker(n);
    }

    private static int recursiveWorker(int n){
        efficiency++;
        if (n == 0){
            return 0;
        }else if (n == 1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(2, recursiveWorker(n - 1)), recursiveWorker(n - 2));
        }
    }
}
```

SequenceCalc.java:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @author Matthew Miller
 * SequenceCalc/GUI class
 */

public class SequenceCalc extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5799806787577444436L;

    private String calcMethod = "iterative";

    private final JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    private final JRadioButton iterativeRadio = new JRadioButton("Iterative",true);
    private final JRadioButton recursiveRadio = new JRadioButton("Recursive");
    private final ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private final JTextField inputBox = new JTextField();
    private final JTextField resultBox = new JTextField();
    private final JTextField efficiencyBox = new JTextField();

    public SequenceCalc(){
        iterativeRadio.addActionListener(this);
        recursiveRadio.addActionListener(this);
        calcButton.addActionListener(this);

        resultBox.setEditable(false);
        efficiencyBox.setEditable(false);

        radioGroup.add(iterativeRadio);
        radioGroup.add(recursiveRadio);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 3");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1,1,1));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        JPanel nRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,1,1));
        nRow.add(iterativeRadio);
        nRow.add(recursiveRadio);
        mainPanel.add(nRow);
        nRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,1,1));
        nRow.add(inputBox);
        nRow.add(calcButton);
        mainPanel.add(nRow);
        nRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,1,1));
        nRow.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
        nRow.add(resultBox);
        mainPanel.add(nRow);
        nRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,1,1));
        nRow.add(new JLabel("Efficiency:"));
        nRow.add(efficiencyBox);
        mainPanel.add(nRow);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    writeFile(generateReport(0,10));
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == iterativeRadio){
            calcMethod = "iterative";
        }else if(e.getSource() == recursiveRadio){
            calcMethod = "recursive";
        }else if(calcMethod == null){
            resultBox.setText("Select a calculation method");
        }else{
            try{
                int n = Integer.parseInt(inputBox.getText());
                if (e.getSource() == calcButton){
                    if(calcMethod == "iterative"){
                        resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.computeIterative(n)));
                        efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.getEfficiency()));
                    }else if(calcMethod == "recursive"){
                        resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.computeRecursive(n)));
                        efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.getEfficiency()));
                    }
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException e2){
                resultBox.setText("Invalid entry");
            }catch (ArithmeticException e3){
                resultBox.setText(e3.getMessage());
            }catch (Exception e4){
                resultBox.setText("Something bad happened");
            }
        }
    }

    public static String generateReport(int start, int end){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Value of n,").append("Iterative,").append("Recursive\n");
        for (int i=start;i<=end;i++){
            //sb.append(i).append(",");
            //Sequence.computeIterative(i);
            sb.append(Sequence.computeIterative(i)).append(",");
            sb.append(Sequence.getEfficiency()).append(",");
            Sequence.computeRecursive(i);
            sb.append(Sequence.getEfficiency()).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void writeFile(String content){
        try{
            Writer fd = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("efficiency.csv"), "utf-8"));
            fd.write(content);
            fd.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SequenceCalc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the conditional branching in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` is quite complex and prone to bugs. This implementation does too many things at the same time: sets the `calcMethod` value, determines which calculation method to use and executes the calculation. These concerns should be separated. Each GUI element should trigger only the changes that are relevant to its responsibility. `JRadioButton`s, when clicked, should define the calculation method to use; `calcButton` should trigger the calculation.

Without significant changes to the design of `SequenceCalc` class, the separation of these concerns can be achieved as follows.

In order to extract the selection of the calculation method, we will use a simple interface

```
interface CalculationRunner {

  int runCalculation(int times);

}
```

It has two ad-hoc anonymous implementations:

```
private static final CalculationRunner RUNNER_ITERATIVE = new CalculationRunner() {

  @Override
  public int runCalculation(int times) {
    return Sequence.computeIterative(times);
  }
};

private static final CalculationRunner RUNNER_RECURSIVE = new CalculationRunner() {

  @Override
  public int runCalculation(int times) {
    return Sequence.computeRecursive(times);
  }
};
```

The reference to the currently chosen method will be stored in a dedicated field:

```
// let's say that it will be initialiazed to "iterative", since the 
// iterativeRadio is selected by default
private CalculationRunner runner = RUNNER_ITERATIVE;
```

We do not need `String calcMethod` field in this class any more.

The events handling will be separate for each element of the GUI. In the constructor:

```
iterativeRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SequenceCalc.this.runner = RUNNER_ITERATIVE;
  }
});

recursiveRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SequenceCalc.this.runner = RUNNER_RECURSIVE;
  }
});
```

The main logic of the action will now be reduced to the following:

```
calcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      int n = Integer.parseInt(inputBox.getText());
      final int result = SequenceCalc.this.runner.runCalculation(n);
      resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(result));
      efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(Sequence.getEfficiency()));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
      resultBox.setText("Invalid entry");
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e3) {
      resultBox.setText(e3.getMessage());
    }
  }
});
```

And there is no more need to implement `ActionListener` for `SequenceCalc`, `actionPerformed` should be deleted from it.

#### Other Stuff

1. The solution above is just a quick ad-hoc tip. Personally, from the point of view of the style, I don't like in-line anonymous implementations. They can be extracted in dedicated entities.
2. I doubt a lot about the `static` methods and `static efficiency` member in `Sequence`. This should be a normal object without statics.
3. The constructor is too long. It should be split based on semantic parts (GUI elements, listeners, frame config etc).
4. `catch (Exception e4)` is ugly, I removed it from the main action processing.

Comment: I would definitely go for enumerations instead of `private static final` implementations of interfaces. Note that interfaces can be implemented by enumerations.

Comment: Interesting how we ended up with the same kind of long answer ;-)

Comment: @Matthieu 1) I think that using statics for the implemented interface is optional here: they are just easier to access from the action listeners and underline the statelessness here. 2) yes, it's the same kind of long answer + diff of only 2 minutes for both the posts :)

Comment: took the words out of my mouth, especially the part about getting rid of the inline runners and going with separate entities.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I never truly understood the purpose of interfaces until reading all of this.

Answer (score 2):

`if(calcMethod == "iterative")` will work in Java because of [String caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java), but in general you should be using `if("iterative".equals(calcMethod)))`.

You could use [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) to set your `calcMethod` member:

```
iterativeRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calcMethod = "iterative";
    }
});
```

which will ease up the code in you "main" `actionPerformed()` method.

To take it one step further, if you have a fixed number of calculation methods, you'd be happier using [Java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). It basically is a fixed set of *class instances* (not only named numbers):

```
public enum Sequence {

    ITERATIVE {
        @Override
        public int compute(int n) {
            // TODO do the computation and compute efficiency
            return 0;
        }
    },

    RECURSIVE {
        @Override
        public int compute(int n) {
            // TODO do the computation and compute efficiency
            return 0;
        }
    };

    // Regular class definition with members and methods

    private int efficiency;

    public int getEfficency() {
        return efficiency;
    }

    // Abstract method to be implemented by all enum instances
    public abstract int compute(int n);

}
```

You can then map one or the other to a client property on your radio button:

```
iterativeRadio.putClientProperty("seq", Sequence.ITERATIVE);
recursiveRadio.putClientProperty("seq", Sequence.RECURSIVE);
```

and transform your `String calcMethod` into `Sequence calcMethod`. Then use the same `ActionListener` on all your radio buttons:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calcMethod = (Sequence)((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).getCLientProperty("seq");
    }
};
iterativeRadio.addActionListener(al);
recursiveRadio.addActionListener(al);
```

Your "main" `actionPerformed()` would then boil down to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    try{
        int n = Integer.parseInt(inputBox.getText());
        resultBox.setText(String.valueOf(calcMethod.compute(n)));
        efficiencyBox.setText(String.valueOf(calcMethod.getEfficiency()));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e2){
        resultBox.setText("Invalid entry");
    }catch (ArithmeticException e3){
        resultBox.setText(e3.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e4){
        resultBox.setText("Something bad happened");
    }
}
```

Neat, isn't it? :)